# React-Native - Firebase data in TextInput

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, render

I could retrieve data from Firebase and display it immediately after. But when I try to use it in render, it is blank. I am new to react-native and might be doing something incorrect. How can I use data from Firebase in render ?

Here is my code:

```
    componentWillMount() {
    firebase.database().ref('/users/' +       userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
                                                               var       DisplayEmail = snapshot.val().Email;                                                                       alert(DisplayEmail);
                                                               });
```

}

```
 render() { 
        return (

           {alert(this.props.DisplayEmail)}

          <TextInput style={styles.input}
            autoFocus = {true}
            autoCorrect = {false}
            autoCapitalize = "none"
            placeholder={this.DisplayEmail}
            keyboardType="email-address"
            underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
            editable={false}
            />

    )
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you want to have something display on render, you should put it on state. By changing the state, you would cause the page to re-render and be updated with the new state. So when you do your firebase call, add it to state.

```
componentWillMount() {
  firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId).on('value', snapshot => {
    this.setState({ DisplayEmail: snapshot.val().Email });
  });
}
```

Calling set state just merges your state changes with your current state. Now you should be able to call state from render and have it work.

```
render() { 
  return (
    {alert(this.props.DisplayEmail)}
    <TextInput style={styles.input}
      autoFocus={true}
      autoCorrect={false}
      autoCapitalize="none"
      placeholder={this.state.DisplayEmail}
      keyboardType="email-address"
      underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
      editable={false}
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it must be work :)

```
     componentWillMount() {
     firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId)
               .on('value', snapshot => {
                       this.state = { DisplayEmail: snapshot.val().Email
         });

}
```

---

```
 render() { 
    return (

       {alert(this.props.DisplayEmail)}

      <TextInput style={styles.input}
        autoFocus = {true}
        autoCorrect = {false}
        autoCapitalize = "none"
        placeholder={this.state.DisplayEmail}
        keyboardType="email-address"
        underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
        editable={false}
        />

)
```

}

Comment: For some reason, alert shows undefined, textinput is blank and when I am returning from this screen to the previous, values seem to display for a sec without giving any control and goes back to the previous screen.